# Symfony 2.8(Wamp) : [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException] PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]

Tags: symfony, console, entity, wamp

I try to create some entity to my  Symfony projet using the console with the following command :

> php app/console doctrine:generate:entity

but when i choose a name for it , i get this error :

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException] PDOException:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it

and this is my parameters.yml on my symfony project :

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_port: 3306
database_name: symfony
database_user: root
database_password: root
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

I  tried to replace 127.0.0.1 by Localhost but it still the same.

Im on Windows 7 and i use Wamp.

EDIT : My port number is 3307 ... Problem solved !

Answer (score 0):

If you are using *127.0.0.1* then you need to specify a port (3306 in most cases). If you use *localhost* instead, the argument port will be ignored. Specifying the port number might work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

It has to come from you db config: either your parameters are wrong for your db, either your db server rejects the connection even though the parameters are good.

what DBMS are you using?

Some DBMS require additional config (like Oracle).

If i were you i would first check that i am using the right pdo driver for my DBMS.